# catching Enter in a multiline Fyne Entry widget (more generally, calling "parent classes")

Tags: go, subclassing, fyne

This question is more about Go than Fyne. Having extended Fyne's Entry widget is the prescribed fashion, I want to detect when Enter (Return) is pressed and use it as a signal that I need to act on the content of the Entry. I want Shift-Return to add a newline to the text without signalling that I need to act.

Given a struct that starts with

```
type myEntry struct {
    widget.Entry
    .....more... }
```

It's easy enough to add

```
func (m *myEntry) TypedKey(key *fyne.KeyEvent) {
    if key.Name == "Return" {
            ///send m.Text somewhere...
    } else {
        //WRONG: m.(*widget.Entry).TypedKey(key) //give Key to Entry widget to process
    }
}
```

but the else clause doesn't compile. So after having decided this isn't a Key I want to intercept, how do I give it back to widget.Entry? Other questions here about calling "base classes", which Go doesn't quite have, don't seem to cover this case.

I thought I could finesse this by adding

```
type myEntry struct {
    widget.Entry
    me *Fyne.Focusable
```

and setting me to the address of myEntry on creation, so I could simply call me.TypedKey. But keys were not handled, and then there was a crash. Setting me=&myNewEntryObject on creation apparently isn't sufficiently "widget.Entry-like" to win the day.

I know Go isn't an OO language, but extending a type and then redirecting calls back to the parent type is a fundamental programming technique; I'd go as far as saying there's no point in extending a struct if you can't get back to the "base struct's" behaviour from the extension. What am I missing?

Comment: You should avoid using string literals when doing a comparison like == "Return" and instead a platform constant, such as fyne.KeyReturn.

Comment: It's not a parent class (Go doesn't have classes so there's no question of hierarchy). It's just an embedded type. Go does a pretty sensible thing here, as seen in [andy.xyz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59753238/1256452): you just use the same name you used to embed with (minus any package qualifier at the front).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded types without a name can be referenced using the name of the type - so the following will work:

```
func (m *myEntry) TypedKey(key *fyne.KeyEvent) {
    if key.Name == "Return" {
            // send m.Text somewhere...
    } else {
        Entry.TypedKey(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's actually m.Entry.TypedKey(key) (and not m.widget.Entry.TypedKey(key) as I'd originally tried. Go is weirdly irregular in some ways.) Worked once the syntax was right.

Comment: Yes, this is because widget is the package name - it's only needed when the scope is otherwise unknown. In this situation you are referencing an "Entry" element within myEntry type.

Comment: This is a Go question and not related to the original, but I'm curious. Assume I needed to compose a type from two other types in different packages, but they happened to have the same type name:
struct Composition {
    foo.Gnarly;
    bar.Gnarly; //huh, they picked the same name. Gee.
}

how would you resolve it if you can't fully specify the type in the code?

Comment: You would have to name one of the fields and then reference that one as a normal struct element.